# Photos JPEG Export Keywords

Tags: photos, photos.app, exif

I have a photo in Photos that I have added keywords (tags) to. When I export this image I can see other metadata, such as description and location that were added by Photos in the EXIF data but not the keywords. Is it possible to make Photos also add the keywords to the EXIF data?

If I export originals there is also an option to export XMP data, but I don't see this option when exporting as JPEG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tags are stored not in EXIF data but in IPTC tags. I was able to view and modify them using the `iptc` command, which uses [libiptcdata](http://libiptcdata.sourceforge.net).

Viewing the tags:

```
$ iptc test.jpg
```

Adding a tag:

```
$ iptc -a Keywords -v testing test.jpg
```